# 5.1 Soundcard (Cheap)

Tags: sound

I was wondering if anyone can recommend me a 5.1 soundcard that is relatively easy to get working on Ubuntu 10.10

The built in sound on the motherboard is giving feedback so I can hear the hard drives spinning and accessing data through the speakers, I assume this would be fixed with a dedicated sound card.

My motherboard has PCI and PCI-e slots available.

Comment: You may wish to try the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) or [IRC](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community) for questions of this nature (Discussion/Objective). For more information on questions which work best on this site see our [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: I can also recommend chat.superuser.com for this purpose (or maybe even chat.askubuntu.com)